# How to handle errors manually when using a dependency in kotlin language that target JVM specifically ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

In my source code,

I use this code:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO)
val response: HttpResponse = client.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
```

in which it is defined in this package `io.ktor.client`.
In this instance, if `io.ktor.client.HttpClient.get()` method throws an exception, my app will crash.
I am developing android app, so maybe if an error occurs, maybe I would write it to a local file or something that does not throw exception.

What I tried:

I tried to find the source code for `io.ktor.client.HttpClient.get()` method in the .gradle folder.
Inside caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor folder, I tried to find the source code either in .kt or .java file, but could not find it.

I thought if I could manually re-writes the dependency I am using to not throw Exception so that I could manually handle the error in my application. But it was not found.

Expectation:

Is there a way to override the error handling implementaion ? perhaps a method to override ?

Comment: Couldn't you surround the `get` call with a try-catch? Or perhaps https://ktor.io/docs/response-validation.html#non-2xx is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
if(error_code!=200):
    print("unsuccessful http 
    request")
```

Sorry, I give you the code in other pseudo language. But I hope you get the point.